# Count of result in group by query based on string length comparison of a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| id | message                                                    | status |
|----|------------------------------------------------------------|--------|
| 1  | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                                 | pass   |
| 2  | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur                    | fail   |
| 3  | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit   | fail   |
|    | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit   |
```

I want to be able to select the count of records with group by status. When a message string length is more than a certain number, I would like it's contribution towards the count to be `ceil(message_length/certain_number)`. For example, the 3rd message length is more than 70 characters. So, it should be counted as 2 instead of just 1.

How should I go about it?

I've tried the below query where I use `group_concat` on the message string but I know it's a wrong solution.

```
select ceil((char_length(group_concat(`message`)) - (count(`message`) - 1))/70) as count, `status` from `table` group by `status`
```

The `- (count(message) - 1)` part was used to consider the commas introduced by `group_concat` function.

The expected results for the query are:

```
| count | status |
|-------|--------|
|   1   |  pass  |
|   3   |  fail  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below query gave me the solution:

```
select sum(count), status from (select ceil(char_length(message)/70) as count, status from table) as data group by status
```

I didn't know it was that simple.